# Display alphabetical query in 3 columns

Tags: php

I'm trying show results from a query in a horizontal (3 columns) right now it's displaying the results in a straight down vertical form.

This is the current result:

[image]

This is the code:

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT UCASE(LEFT(Name, 1)) AS letter FROM parts ORDER BY Name';
$myconn = $con->query($query);

if ($myconn) {
while ($row = $myconn->fetch_object()) {
$letter = htmlentities($row->letter);
echo "<a href='#$letter'>$letter</a> | ";
}}
$query = 'SELECT Name FROM parts ORDER BY Name';
$myconn = $con->query($query);
if ($myconn) {
$row = $myconn->fetch_object();
while ($row) {
$c = $row->Name[0];
$letter = htmlentities(strtoupper($c));
echo '<div class="row justify-content-lg-center">';
echo "<h4 id='$letter'>$letter</h4>";
do {
 echo "<a href='#$letter'>";
 echo  htmlentities($row->Name), '<br /></a>';
 echo '</div>';
 }while ($row = $myconn->fetch_object() and $row->Name[0] == $c);
 }
 }
```

This is the result I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: can you show the result that you are getting now

Comment: This is how it looks now. looks now: https://imgur.com/a/iJ4ekeA

Comment: This doesn't sound like PHP issue at all. It sounds more like HTML/CSS problem

Comment: You might find [CSS Columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) useful.

Comment: Unrelated to the current issue, but your code has a query inside a loop. This is bad design, and you should look at different ways of achieving the desired outcome.